# GitHub PR Help. How to add user?

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a PR that has been submitted that I have requested small updates/ changes to be made to. The user has switched GitHub profiles during the time the PR was open to the time I reviewed the PR.  He now wants to be able to submit the changes to the PR as his new username.  Is there a way to give the new user write access to the PR?

Here is a [link](https://github.com/cmseaton42/node-ethernet-ip/pull/44) to the PR for reference.

Comment: Does the old account still exist? The _contributor_ should be able to let the new account contribute changes to _their_ repository and branch. This should update the existing PR.

Comment: I have requested the user do this.  I think that this will be the best way.

Comment: @chris, thanks for the suggestion!